# Enabling button in jquery mobile pop-up

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, popup

I have a Jquery pop-up that contains a form, and the submit button disabled. The button is supposed to get enabled once all fields have been filled. I ran a javascript script for this. However, it didn't work, and the page got refreshed. I added another button just to test the enabling.

<'button id="submitButton" disabled='true' data-theme="b" data-icon="check">Done<'/button'>

<'button id="x" onclick="enableButton()"'>Enable<'/button'>

The script:

```
function enableButton()
{

   document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled=false;

}
```

This didn't work. I tried scripting it according to the jquery plugin guidelines like so:

```
$("#x").onclick(function()
{                                      
   $("#submitButton").button('enable');
});
```

This didn't work either. Any idea why? Again, this form is in a jquery pop-up.

Comment: Can you show your code? create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#submitButton").removeAttr('disabled');
```

In your click event

Comment: Didn't work :/ And when I click the enable button, it takes me back to the page from which I opened the pop-up, with the URL appended with the form elements. I removed the submit attribute from the form button, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Okay, I just tested the code with two buttons on a page and it works perfectly. One button is diabled, and I used the other to enable it on click. The problem I have arises when the buttons are within a pop-up. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
$("#submitButton").removeClass('ui-disabled');
```